# SQL IN condtion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-in

```
select transferTypes from TransferData 

transferTypes 
--------------
TTH, TT
TRANSIT, TTH
ST, TRANSIT
TRANSIT, TTH
ST, TT
```

Is there is any way or inbuilt function to achieve below results?

Tried with below `IN` condition but unable to get required results.

**Expecting Result:**

```
select transferTypes from TransferData where transferTypes in ('TT, ST')

transferTypes 
-------------
TTH, TT
ST, TRANSIT
ST, TT

select transferTypes from TransferData where transferTypes in ('TTH, TRANSIT')

transferTypes 
-------------
TTH, TT
TRANSIT, TTH
ST, TRANSIT
TRANSIT, TTH

select transferTypes from TransferData where transferTypes in ('TT')

transferTypes 
-------------
TTH, TT
ST, TT
```

Comment: [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to convert your lists (in recrods) to form such that it starts and ends with comma and contains no spaces. Then you can use `charindex` combined with `or` operator to check if particular values or included in records:

```
declare @TransferData  table (transferTypes varchar(20));
insert into @TransferData values
('TTH, TT'),
('TRANSIT, TTH'),
('ST, TRANSIT'),
('TRANSIT, TTH'),
('ST, TT');

select * from (
    select ',' + replace(transferTypes, ' ', '') + ',' transferTypes from @TransferData
) a
where charindex(',TT,', transferTypes) > 0
or charindex(',ST,', transferTypes) > 0
```

Answer (score 13):

Easiest way is using `string_split` which was introduced in SQL Server 2016 and later.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT a.transferTypes
FROM 
    TransferData a
CROSS APPLY 
    string_split([transferTypes], ',') b
WHERE 
    TRIM(b.[value]) IN ('TT', 'ST')
```

The above splits out all values in `transferTypes` and allows you to search by individual values. If you're using a version lower than SQL Server 2016, you can always create a function to do the exact same (E.g. [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string) )

**================================================**

**A little explanation of what** `string_split` **does**:

`string_split` is a table valued function which in short means that the function will output a table. Given a string input, `string_split` will output multiple rows of substrings based on a delimiter that you specify.

Take the following for example:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    string_split('String1;String2;String3', ';')
```

The above code will return three rows as shown below:

[image: Three string rows returned]

This is very powerful for the original question as it allows us to filter directly to single values without needing to use `CHARINDEX` or `LIKE`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an illustrative example on how to achieve this. Use variables obvious in the selects. You never specified how many items would be in your delimited list, so I make the assumption of 2 based on the sample data.

If it's varied then perhaps some form of Dynamic SQL might be the order of the day.

```
create table #transferdata
( 
 transferTypes  varchar(100) 
) 

insert into #transferdata select 'TTH, TT'
insert into #transferdata select 'TRANSIT, TTH'
insert into #transferdata select 'ST, TRANSIT'
insert into #transferdata select 'TRANSIT, TTH'
insert into #transferdata select  'ST, TT'


;WITH tmp AS
(
    SELECT

        LEFT(transferTypes , CHARINDEX(',', transferTypes  + ',') - 1) as col1 ,
        ltrim(STUFF(transferTypes , 1, CHARINDEX(',', transferTypes  + ','), '')) as col2
    FROM #transferdata

)
SELECT * into #tmp 
FROM tmp;

select * from #tmp as t where (t.col1 = 'tt' or t.col2 = 'tt') or (t.col1 = 'st' or t.col2 = 'st')
select * from #tmp as t where (t.col1 = 'tth' or t.col2 = 'tth') or (t.col1 = 'transit' or t.col2 = 'transit')
select * from #tmp as t where (t.col1 = 'tt' or t.col2 = 'tt') or (t.col1 = 'tt' or t.col2 = 'tt')


drop table #tmp
drop table #transferdata
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
select 
  transferTypes 
from 
  TransferData 
where 
  transferTypes like '%TT%'
  or transferTypes like '%ST%'
```